# Insert a character after third character in a string

Tags: shopify, liquid

In Liquid I am attempting to insert a specific character '-' after the third character in a string. I have been able to use `append` and `prepend` to add the '-' to the beginning or end of the string, however I am unsure of how to insert this at a specific point.

Example: `{% capture userphone %} {{current_user.phone | append: '-' }} {% endcapture %}`

```
{{userphone}} == '1231231234-'
```

Is there a method that can be utilized with liquid to insert hyphens after character 3 and 6?

```
{{userphone}} == '123-123-1234'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution with `slice` filter:

```
{%- assign phone = '1231231234' -%}
{%- assign part1 = phone | slice: 0, 3 -%}
{%- assign part2 = phone | slice: 3, 3 -%}
{%- assign part3 = phone | slice: 6, 4 -%} 
{{ part1 | append: '-' | append: part2 | append: '-' | append: part3 }}
```

The above solution implies that you're sure that the phone number contains 10 characters. It can be slightly adjusted by changing the length value to the real string size or just to some value e.g. `999` to be sure that the last part contains all characters.

---

You can also you `for` loop:

```
{%- assign phone = '1231231234' -%}
{%- assign phoneChars = phone | split: '' -%}
{%- assign phoneWithHyphens = '' -%}
{%- for char in phoneChars -%}
  {%- assign phoneWithHyphens = phoneWithHyphens | append: char -%}
  {%- if forloop.index == 3 or forloop.index == 6 -%}
    {%- assign phoneWithHyphens = phoneWithHyphens | append: '-' -%}
  {%- endif -%}
{%- endfor -%}
{{- phoneWithHyphens -}}
```